# Why does CloudFront sometimes serve gzip instead of br, when both are enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am reading the CloudFront documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html, retrieved June 20, 2021) regarding CloudFront compression:

> The viewer includes the Accept-Encoding HTTP header in the request, and the header values include gzip, br, or both. This indicates that the viewer supports compressed content. When the viewer supports both formats, CloudFront uses Brotli.

My plain reading of this is that if a request is made with the following header:

> accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Then CloudFront should use Brotli.

However, observing our production web apps (which uses the `Managed-CachingOptimized` cache policy which has both gzip and br enabled) served via CloudFront, I can simply see that this is NOT the case - about 70% of the files are served using Brotli, while the remainder use gzip.

[image]

What's even more confusing is that all these files are part of the same compilation, served via the same origin, having the same metadata. I don't see how they differ at all, other than content and size.

My only intuition is that CloudFront in some cases determines that gzip produces a better file size than br, and thus decides to use that instead, but I cannot find this behavior documented.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try one thing. Invalidate all your cache in CloudFront and then reload your web app in the browser by disabling the cache from dev tools. After that share the headers info.

Comment: It is either a caching issues as said by @LovekeshKumar or not all the requests have the header `accept-encoding` properly set.

Comment: It happens to me once also, but I invalidate the cloudfront cache and remove my browser cache. After that things worked well.

Comment: @StefanN I have confirmed that all the requests have the `accept-encoding` header properly set - especially the ones responding with gzip. It is always `gzip, deflate, br`, as that is what Chrome passes. We do not tamper with any of the request headers on the client side.

Comment: @LovekeshKumar thanks, I tried that initially (both on the CloudFront and client side) but it unfortunately didn't resolve it. I still get a mix of brotli and gzip responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after speaking to AWS support about this, I found the issue.

In short - if the FIRST request for a CloudFront resource (i.e. before it is cached) only supports gzip, then ALL future requests to that (now cached) resource will be served using gzip, even if the client specifies that it supports brotli.

The reason this happened to us is that we use Cypress to run automated tests against our webapps. Cypress currently only supports gzip when making requests to a target site (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6197#issuecomment-684847493), and would occasionally be the first to access new files as we uploaded them - causing them to be permanently cached as gzip.

The only resolution I found for now is to, as @LovekeshKumar suggested in a comment, manually clear the CloudFront cache, and then immediately fetch all the files via Chrome or something else that supports Brotli. Strange and tedious, but hopefully this will be solved both on the AWS and Cypress side of things eventually.

Comment: Hi @csvan did you find a better solution?
Even if I hit with Chrome right after I invalidate the cache I still get my file being served with gzip.
The only way that works for me is to invalidate the cache and then hit the specific asset (css or js file) with a http client like Postman or RapidAPI with `"accept-encoding: br"` only. 
After that I can see that my files are served using brotli.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your origin probably supports only gzip compression and returns gzip to CloudFront. Then CloudFront can't compress the content and caches the gzip response as it is.

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

> **Origin is already configured to compress objects**
>
> If you configure CloudFront to compress objects and the origin also compresses objects,
> the origin should include a Content-Encoding header, which indicates
> to CloudFront that the object is already compressed. When a response
> from an origin includes the Content-Encoding header, CloudFront does
> not compress the object, regardless of the header’s value. CloudFront
> sends the response to the viewer and caches the object in the edge
> location.

As a solution, at the origin you can add a custom header or check the User-Agent to identify CloudFront, and then not compress the response.