# CloudFront make website WordPress redirect to page alphabet after time duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We're facing a persistent issue with our WordPress sites that use CloudFront for caching and compression. Despite enabling both gzip and Brotli compression, we've noticed that after around 3 weeks, the cache fails to clear properly, resulting in a redirection to an alphabetically sorted page.
We've researched and tested our setup, discovering that CloudFront handles compression and accept-encoding since our Apache server doesn't use any compression method. We've also found that clearing the cache temporarily resolves the issue until it resurfaces. It seems that only gzip compression is enabled while Brotli compression is disabled, even though Brotli offers better compression and smaller file sizes. We'd appreciate any insights into why this behavior occurs.

Researching Stack Overflow posts on supporting gzip and Brotli (e.g., this post: [Why does CloudFront sometimes serve gzip instead of br, when both are enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054148/why-does-cloudfront-sometimes-serve-gzip-instead-of-br-when-both-are-enabled)) but I've still understood it.
Can someone explain why this happens?